# What is the best way to search multiple lists based on a criteria list in python?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have:

```
list1 = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror', 0, 'blue']
list2 = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror']
list3 = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]
list4 = ['subsection', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]
```

What is the best way to use `criteria_list` below to select only the lists that partially match the beginning elements of `criteria_list` and also exclude certain keywords elements that follow e.g the `mirror` element?

```
criteria_list = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3]
```

Desired match would be:

```
list3 = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]
```

This is because it partially matches `criteria_list` and does not include the string `'mirror'`.

I hope my question is clear and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: While you could hardcode this, it is starting to look like a job for a database. Take a look at sqlite (it's built in to Python - try `import sqlite3`).

Comment: So the first 4 elements should match criteria_list, and then the next element should be anything other than 'mirror'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this code :

```
final_list = [['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror', 0, 'blue'], ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror'], ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',], 
['subsection', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]]

criteria_list = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3]

cp = True
exclude_keyword = 'mirror'

for each_list in final_list:
    for check in criteria_list:
            if check in each_list and exclude_keyword not in each_list:
                cp = True
            else:        
                cp = False
    if cp == True:
            print(each_list)
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, this is something more of what I was looking for, The only issue is the result includes:
`['subsection', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]`
This should not be a match as criteria list does not have subsection in it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_lists = [
    ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror', 0, 'blue'],
    ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror'],
    ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light'],
    ['subsection', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light']
]
```

You could hardcode something like

```
def is_match(lst):
    return (
        len(lst) >= 5
        and lst[0] == 'section'
        and lst[1] == 'section'
        and lst[2] == 'section'
        and lst[3] == 3
        and lst[4] != 'mirror'
    )

matches = [lst for lst in list_of_lists if is_match(lst)]
```

but this is very inflexible. You could build a system like

```
def make_item_matcher(offs, value):
    def item_matcher(lst):
        return len(lst) > offs and lst[offs] == value
    return item_matcher

def make_item_not_matcher(offs, value):
    def item_not_matcher(lst):
        return len(lst) <= offs or lst[item] != value
    return item_not_matcher

def find_matches(criteria, items):
    return [item for item in items if all(crit(item) for crit in criteria)]

matches = find_matches(
    [
        make_item_matcher(0, 'section'),
        make_item_matcher(1, 'section'),
        make_item_matcher(2, 'section'),
        make_item_matcher(3, 3),
        make_item_not_matcher(4, 'mirror')
    ],
    list_of_lists
)
```

but that really isn't much better.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to convert criteria_list to a String. Whenever you want to see if a inputlist partially match the beginning of criteria_list, you use **str.startswith** to perform the comparison. Then come to exclude part, we also use **str.startswith** to exclude special keywords.

```
def is_startwith(input_list, criteria_list, exclude_keyword):
    is_match = False

    #convert criteria_list to string
    criteria_str = ",".join(str(x) for x in criteria_list)

    #convert input_list to string
    input_list_str = ",".join(str(x) for x in input_list)

    #see if input_list partially match the beginning of criteria_list
    is_match = str.startswith(input_list_str, criteria_str) 

    #see if we need to exclude keywords
    if is_match and str.startswith(input_list_str[len(criteria_str) + 1:] , exclude_keyword):
        is_match = False

    return is_match

#our test data
list1 = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror', 0, 'blue']
list2 = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'mirror']
list3 = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]
list4 = ['subsection', 'section', 'section', 3, 'light',]
criteria_list = ['section', 'section', 'section', 3]
exclude_keyword = 'mirror'

# should return False and True
print is_startwith(list1, criteria_list, exclude_keyword )
print is_startwith(list3, criteria_list, exclude_keyword )
```